# How to set Laravel Custom Nova Tool as link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-nova

I'm using

```
Laravel: 7.x

Nova:  v3.8.2
```

I want to add a links to specific lenses in 2 different resources as I fount i should use Nova Tools to achieve that.

I created a Nova tool with

```
php artisan nova:tool noad/sidebar-linker
```

i added second view file in (i need 2 links in sidebar)

```
// navigation2.blade.php in dir: nova-components\SidebarLinker\resources\views\

<router-link tag="h3" :to="{name: 'sidebar-linker'}" class="cursor-pointer flex items-center font-normal dim text-white mb-6 text-base no-underline">
<span class="text-white sidebar-label">
     <a href="resources/markets/lens/company-markets" class="text-white sidebar-label">{{__('Sidebar Linker2')}}</a>
</span>
```

And added display of second navigation in SidebarLinker.php:

```
public function renderNavigation()
{
    return view('sidebar-linker::navigation').view('sidebar-linker::navigation2');
}
```

It displays well and support localization, but i have a problem how to make a redirect working, my <a href="" in blade files not working. As i searched about this i should make some routes to handle that but I found nothing in laravel docs about routes in tools.

I Tried to achieve it by laravel custom link packages but the 3 different packages i have tested not support localization.

My question is where and how to setup behavior of clicking link/name on my Custom Nova Tool ?